# PySpark:How to process each row of DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to process each row of DataFrame. Here, the column `feat` contains many elements with format `idx:value`. I want to keep the `idx` that I want.

For example, I want to keep the `idx=1` or `idx=5`.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("u1","1:a 2:k 5:c 6:i"),("u2","2:k 4:p 5:b 6:k")],["id","feat"])
```

`Input:`

```
+---+---------------+
| id|           feat|
+---+---------------+
| u1|1:a 2:k 5:c 6:i|
| u2|2:k 4:p 5:b 6:k|
+---+---------------+
```

`Expected`:

```
+---+---------------+
| id|           feat|
+---+---------------+
| u1|1:a 5:c        |
| u2|5:b            |
+---+---------------+
```

Comment: Is this just a string? too bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my try with several functions.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("u1","1:a 2:k 5:c 6:i"),("u2","2:k 4:p 5:b 6:k")],["id","feat"])

select_idx=[1,5]

df.withColumn('feat', f.explode(f.split('feat', ' '))) \
  .withColumn('feat', f.split('feat', ':')) \
  .filter(f.col('feat')[0].isin(select_idx)) \
  .withColumn('feat', f.concat_ws(':', 'feat')) \
  .groupBy('id').agg(f.collect_list('feat').alias('feat')) \
  .withColumn('feat', f.concat_ws(' ', 'feat')) \
  .show(10, False)

+---+-------+
|id |feat   |
+---+-------+
|u1 |1:a 5:c|
|u2 |5:b    |
+---+-------+
```

Comment: What if I define a variable to express `(1,5)`? How to achieve it like this, `select_idx=[1,5], df.filter(df.feat[0].isin(select_idx))`?